# Blurred menu background overlay

Tags: css

[image: Screenshot]

How can I allow the dropdown menu not to overlap the menu, but to appear as if they were on the same level? And how do I hide the white glow from beneath the dropdown menu?

I tried changing the z-index value, but the problem persists.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: Give us code that you tried so far (HTML and CSS)

Comment: Can I send the link?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the padding top and bottom of the parent link so that the dropdown does not overlay the navnar.

I am not sure how to get rid of the white glow it may have something to do with opacity set to 1.0 for full visibility to navbar and dropdown. The background image can have a different opacity eg. 0.75

P.S. You could just apply opacity to the body tag and not the menu or background might work.